# A speedy way to match a text to multiple regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex, matching, keyword-search

I have about 50000 keyword that regex pattern is applied. My application gets some text content and try to find keywords that are mathcing with this content.

I'm doing this as loop through all keywords and search each of them in the content.

Because There are too many content to match I'm willing to find a better way if exist.

Is there any better way to do it?

This is the sample code I'm currently doing:

```
 List<string> keywords = getKeywords();
        string textToMatch = getNews();

        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        foreach (var keyword in keywords)
        {
            Match r =  Regex.Match(textToMatch, keyword);
            if(r.Success)
                result.Add(keyword)
        }
```

Comment: I think you'd better ask in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) section.

Comment: @Handoko.Chen nope. this does not suit Code Review because there is no code here to be reviewed!

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, I forgot to tell him that he must supply the code to be reviewed.

Comment: @Handoko.Chen there is no reason to move it to code review. I'm asking for a best practice or a different thougth about this case, not for code.

Comment: @mavera How can you expect people to help you to optimize your code if you don't provide the code first.

Comment: @Handoko.Chen Sure I can share code it's simple. But, I want people to focus on the way I did, not code.

Comment: @Handoko.Chen I shared a sample code because of you. waiting for your advice now :)

Comment: @mareva I'm not an expert in RE, in fact I hate it because it's slowness. But I see that you use the static method of Regex class. I read that there is a way to speed up the Regex calls. See [this article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-performance) and [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2004/11/12/256783.aspx). Alternatively, if the strings are simple, you can use regular string methods. See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oanapl/archive/2009/04/04/performance-comparison-regex-versus-string-operations.aspx) for comparison between Regex and string methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94405/discussion-between-mavera-and-handoko-chen).

Comment: Why use regular expressions? If the keywords are plain text then using `if(textToMatch.Contains(keyword)){result.Add(keyword);}` may be faster.

Comment: @AdrianHHH there are some cases about keywords force me to use regex. But, I'll check if I can eliminate regex at least part of keywords. thanks.

Comment: Keywords and a need for regex? Maybe I don't understand them correctly. But if so maybe it's an option to build one big regex and use it. But I'm sure that this won't be the fastest way even if you combine some together to reduce backtracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we think only one text to match with multiple keywords there is no completly different way to work on. We can just use `Parallel.For`, compiled regex etc.

In my case, I get too much text messages to match with keywords. Let's assume I have 50 text and 50000 keywords. Normally I go to keyword loop for each texts. Now, first I merged all text into one big text. Then run match for it. Matched keyword list will be returned. Finally, run match for each text again but only for matched keyword list.

Comment: This does not answer the question. I know you are answering your own question but please add more details so others may benefit by learning what you have done.

Comment: @AdrianHHH thanks for advise. I've added more info. I can do more according to demands.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can use `RegexOptions.Compiled` which instructs the regular expression engine to compile the regular expression expression into IL using lightweight code generation. Program will start slower, but matches using the regular expression are faster.

Next step would be some nice implementantion of Consumer Producer design pattern. Sadly I dont know what is slowest in your operations but if you try implement this pattern it should be faster (some pseudocode below)

```
        BlockingCollection<string> collection = new BlockingCollection<string>();
        Action productionAction = () =>
        {
           //produce data then
            collection.Add(ProcessedData);
        };
        Action consumentAction = () =>
        {
           //consume data
            var data = collection.Take();
            //then
            //do your things

        };
        Parallel.Invoke(productionAction,consumentAction);
        // code will end here when everything will be processed
        // also you can change Action to TaskRun to use some Multithreading
```

You can also try easiest way that can improve performence significally (or not! I do not have knowledge of rest of your code!) by replacing your loop with  [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried all you told here. Parallel functions works very well, but because I already work multi thread and cpu is already so busy, it didn't get any profit.